# OCaml: use match and type casting

Tags: ocaml

I'm a beginner and the terms I used may not be accurate.

I have

```
type t = True | False | If of t * t * t | Int of int | Plus of t * t | GT of t * t

let isval t =
  match t with
      True|False -> true
    | Int _ -> true
    | _ -> false
```

I want to implement a eval function.

```
let rec step t =
   match isval t with
      true -> raise NormalForm
    | false -> match t with
          If(t1, t2, t3) when t1=True -> t2
        | If(t1, t2, t3) when t1=False -> t3
        | Plus(t1, t2) -> t1+t2
        | GT(t1, t2) ->  t1>t2
        | _ -> raise NormalForm;;
```

Error occurs at `Plus(t1, t2) -> t1+t2`, saying "This expression has type t but an expression was expected of type int".

What is the problem? How should I fix it?

Answer (score 3):

As the compiler says the `+` operator works on ints. But you're applying it to subexpressions of type `t`. Since your type `t` can represent things like `Plus(True, False)`, you need to decide how you actually want to handle these cases.

You also need to decide on a return type. Some of your cases seem to be returning `bool`, others return `t`, and others return `int`. From the look of things, you might want to return `t` in all cases. If so, you would return `Int n` instead of just plain `n`.

(Basile Starynkevitch has written some code that tackles these problems. Maybe think about them first yourself then look at his code :-)

Answer (score 1):

The `match` expression has (unfortunately) no end-markers. For nested `match` you have to use parenthesis or `begin` ... `end` e.g. code

```
match x with
  SomePattern y -> begin
    match y with
       AnyotherThing -> ....
       YetAnotherPattern z -> ....
  end
```

and you have a type issue: your `step` function is giving an `int` when doing a `t1+t2` and is giving a `bool` when doing `t1>t2`; this is not possible, a function should return some known (single) type.

You may want to define

```
  type result_t = NoResult | IntResult of int | BoolResult of bool
```

and give `IntResult (t1+t2)` or `BoolResult (t1>t2)`

or you could simply have `step` return some `t` value, i.e. `True`, `False`, `Int (t1+t2)`

I would code instead

```
let asint = function Int x -> x | _ -> failwith "not an integer"

let rec eval = function
  True -> True
  | False -> False
  | Int x -> Int x
  |  If (cond,thenpart,elsepart) -> begin
       match eval cond with
         True -> eval thenpart
        | False -> eval elsepart
        | _ -> failwith "bad condition"
    end 
  | Plus (l, r) -> 
       Int (asint (eval l) + asint (eval r))
  | GT (l, r) -> begin
       if (asint (eval l)) > (asint (eval r)) then
         True
       else 
         False
    end
```